# cross or lorraine and AddRemarkLLSRQ?

Tags: soap, sabre, remarks

Using the SOAP API how can I write the cross or lorraine into a remark using AddRemarkLLSRQ?

I have tried using the ascii code but have had no luck

The request is

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:AddRemarkRQ Version="2.1.0">
         <ns:RemarkInfo>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ns:Remark Code="X" Type="General">
               <ns:Text>☨ REMARK 1</ns:Text>
            </ns:Remark>
         </ns:RemarkInfo>
      </ns:AddRemarkRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

The response is

```
  <AddRemarkRS Version="2.1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
     <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-05-12T06:09:21-05:00">
           <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
              <stl:Message>.FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</stl:Message>
              <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
           </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
     </stl:ApplicationResults>
  </AddRemarkRS>
```

Comment: You are not making a whole lot of sense here, you really need to explain all the terms you are using.  Also, add some code, even if it's not working, at least it will give readers an idea about what you're trying to do.

Comment: After creating a session and fetching  a pnr using  TravelItineraryReadRQ we are submitting an AddRemarkLLSRQ request as follows      <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:AddRemarkRQ Version="2.1.0">
         <ns:RemarkInfo>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ns:Remark Code="X" Type="General">
               <ns:Text>☨ REMARK 1</ns:Text>
            </ns:Remark>
         </ns:RemarkInfo>
      </ns:AddRemarkRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>   This errors with 
                  <stl:Message>.FRMT.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</stl:Message>

Comment: I added the "sabre" tag because I think your question is related to that platform, and to attract the right people to this question it's crucial to have the proper tags in place.  Please remove the tag if my assumption is not correct.

Comment: Do you know what caused the problem? I'm getting the same error code (different transaction), but the error message tells me hardly anything.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but for others...

The sample that fizmhd provides is the correct way to implement this.  You do not need to specify the 'cross of lorraine' character as the service will do this for you.

Attributes:
Code = Qualifier (X in your case, "X-qualified remark")
Type = General (a 'general' remark)

The service knows you're trying to add an "X-qualified general remark", so it will put the cross in there for you.

Also note that the cross of lorraine can be tricky.
Sample from Sabre: 5H‡TEST
From jmacagno's comment: ¥
Both are used in different places, so keep them handy.  I often check for both as terminal (agent screen data) can be different from the XML data.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct character used i believe: "¥"

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--
"Code" is used to specify an alpha sorting character.
-->
<!--
"SegmentNumber" is used to specify a segment number.
-->
<!--
"Type" is used to specify the type of remark.  Acceptable values are: Alpha-Coded, Client Address, Corporate, Delivery Address, General, Group Name, Hidden, Historical, Invoice, or Itinerary.
-->


  <!--
Equivalent Sabre host command: 5H‡TEST ALPHA CODED REMARK
-->
<AddRemarkRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
<RemarkInfo>
<Remark Code="H" Type="Alpha-Coded">
<Text>TEST ALPHA CODED REMARK</Text>
</Remark>
</RemarkInfo>
</AddRemarkRQ>
```

This is sample from developer resources of sabre, have you tried this.